# Debugging in ros2

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, buffer

I am stuck in bug of my code.My code currently have one publisher(**pub1**) and two sub(**sub1** and **sub2**).The **sub1** data is processed and than passed to **pub1**.

My **sub1**  msg type involves the header and array of speed value.I am planning to  process the data from each array value.The program works fine for one ,however when I check for all of them the values are not as expected.

Issue:

1)I checked with rqt,ros2topic echo ,however is there any other way to debug iniside the code?

2)My algorithm to process a data might take longer than the publishing rate of pub1.Is there any way I can have some buffer so that later if I optimise my code I don't want to lose any data which I got so far.

Answer (score 1):

If `pub1` passes data to `sub1` and `sub1` passes a result back to `pub1` you may consider **using a service instead** of a publisher/subscriber setup (see [official understanding services tutorial (iron)](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.html)). In that case `pub1` would wait for the response of `sub1` (Keep in mind that you will need a `srv` type instead of your `msg` type).

Regarding (1) `rqt` can measure the message frequency on current topics so you can verify your "might take longer to process data" assumtion.

As mentioned in other answers the "print all the things" apporach might be helpfull. Think about using the ros2 logger ([official tutorial (iron)](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Demos/Logging-and-logger-configuration.html)), which allows you to use `rqt`s `rqt_console` to view them (more pretty way, timestamps and some usefull information).

Answer (score 0):

Well to debug C++ code you can use a classical debugger in addition to the ROS tools. This will give more information on the internals of your code.
If you are not versed into gdb, you can rely on the classical "[print all the things](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26925570)" approach (also works in Python).

As for (2), the buffer is given in the subscriber creation, as part of the quality of service. Note that if the processing time is always larger than the publication period, then the message being processed will be more and more an old one. You need to be able to catch up at some point if this is relevant for your application.